# Is it possible to use Apple Frameworks (ex: GameplayKit, SceneKit) when working with Serverside Swift?

Tags: swift, server-side

I'm a Swift developer & I'd like to write a multiplayer portion of a game, and I'm wondering if I can do it in Swift. I'm familiar with GameplayKit & SceneKit and think it would be neat if I could just use those on the backend. Is using Apple Frameworks possible in the backend?

Comment: If your server is running macOS, yes.

Comment: Interesting! I hadn’t even thought about using a Mac as a server before